# Anyone replicated asp.net4 dropdown menu in MVC3 (or 4) razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Has anyone been able to replicate the dropdown (vertical) menu which you get by default with asp.net 4 template in MVC3 using razor? I can add more horizontal options but would like to be able to replicate the vertical menu subitem list. Is this functionality built in to the default razor template in visual studio?  I tried searching but unable to find some sample code which replicates this.

```
     <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home">
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MenuItem2.aspx" Text="Item2"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MenuItem3.aspx" Text="Item2"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MenuItem4.aspx" Text="Exit"/>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Help.aspx" Text="Help">
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a more capable version of the DropDownList helper?

Comment: Are you talking about a navigation menu or a DropDownList helper that renders a `<select>`?

Comment: a navigational menu like shown at the top of this page. but with submenu items.

Answer (score 0):

A select list or drop down in Razor syntax is:

```
@Html.DropDownList
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor
```

Comment: i have updated the question to show sample code, couldnt add an image as i havent gained enough reputation.

Comment: I would use an plain html <select> element. (this is what is generated when you use @Html.DropDownList).  Or event an unordered list.  I would then apply classes to the menu items and submenu items.  And use CSS and JQuery to control the look at feel of them.